# Weblogic Monitoring Data Source (Jdbc Connection Pool)

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, monitoring, connection-pooling, wlst

I am a beginner in weblogic. I am writing this script in wlst that monitors the number of connections currently made from a jdbc connection pool belonging to a data source.

Here is my understanding of how the admin console works. Jdbc service needs to be defined first and then assigned to a server (or servers) . Once the changes are activated , an instance of the jdbc service gets created on the server.

Following is the wlst jython code snippet that i have written (using the java docs):

```
domainRuntime()
servers=domainRuntimeService.getServerRuntimes()

for server in servers:
 jdbcDSrcs=server.getJDBCServiceRuntime().getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()
 print 'Domain Name         #', cmo.getName()
 print 'Server Name         #', server.getName()
 for jdbaDSrc in jdbcDSrcs:
    print 'Data Source Name #', jdbaDSrc.getName()
    print 'Curr Connc Count #', jdbaDSrc.getActiveConnectionsCurrentCount()
```

**Could you please critique the logic and code ?**

(I do not have access to test environment yet. Hence have not been able to run it. I am pretty much coding in the dark)

Also a lot of examples in the online forums have the following lines:

```
pools= adminHome.getMBeansByType('JDBCConnectionPoolRuntime')
for pool in pools:
  ......
```

**Whats the difference between the code that I have written and the one above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these WLST calls do the same thing but the important bit of info is that `JDBCConnectionPoolRuntimeMBean` has been deprecated and replaced by `getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()` as of Weblogic version 9. See that mentioned here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/management/runtime/JDBCConnectionPoolRuntimeMBean.html

You should prefer the use of your original example:

```
jdbcDSrcs=server.getJDBCServiceRuntime().getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()
```

Unless you are on an even older version of Weblogic. Syntactically the first example looks correct, we do the same thing with 10.3.6.